# Is $\mu: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ a measure or outer measure?

Tags: measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf, outer-measure

Consider the function $\mu: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ defined by

$$\mu(A) := \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot \#(A \cap \{1, \dots, n\})$$

Is this function a measure or an outer measure?

It's easy to see that $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$ and I believe that monotonicity also holds. However, I am unsure if the function is also $\sigma$-additive (or $\sigma$-subadditive). I arrived at the point that
\begin{align*}
\mu\left(\dot{\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}} A_i \right) &= \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot \#\left(\left(\dot{\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}}} A_i \right) \cap \{1, \dots, n\}\right) \\
&= \limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}\#(A_i \cap \{1, \dots, n\})
\end{align*}

However, I don't think that I can pull out the infinite sum that easily. On the other hand, I haven't been able to find a counterexample. I would be thankful for any help!

Comment: Not subadditive, see $A_i=\{i\}$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Thank you, I think that counterexample also works for $\sigma$-additivity, since they're disjoint!

Comment: Clearly $\mu(A) \in [0,1]$ at most.  Also: Not finitely additive.  We can construct a set $A$ with $\mu(A) = 1$ and $\mu(A^c) = 1$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_density